# angularjs selected item not visible in dropdown

Tags: angularjs

I have a complex object like this

```
listItems = [
    { "id": 1, "name": "myname1" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "myname2" },
    { "id": 3, "name": "myname3" }
];
```

I want to create options from above listItems like this

```
<select>
    <option value="1">myname1</option>
    <option value="2">myname2</option>
    <option value="3">myname3</option>
</select>
```

I have used this angularjs code, its generating the correct html code but whatever I select in dropdown is not shown inside the select box

```
<select ng-model="iList" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in listItems track by item.id" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `listItems` is in the `$scope`

```
<select ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in listItems"></select>
```